# How do I add an element to a fieldset?

Tags: forms, 6, webforms

When creating a webform in version 5.18 each element had an option to include it in a selected fieldset.  Worked like a charm.
Now, on version 6.22 I cannot find this option anywhere.  I can't believe they've done away and my research only yields php code which user form creators are not going to use.
Can someone please advise where to find or what to add to bring this feature back?  One post I found elsewhere talks about an 'advanced' area but again, cannot find it anywhere.
Suggestions please?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact in Drupal 6 there is no need to select the parent from the drop box anymore: You drag your field under your fieldset and push it to its right.

[image: In administration]

As result, you get this.

[image: Result]